# How do I uninstall this OS?

Tags: release-hera

I have tried several times to uninstall this OS by installing another OS onto the HD, but each time it has failed at some point. Some installers do not recognize the partition, while others crash when I try to edit it in any way. This OS is way too watered down and not useful to ask for money yet alone act as a virus on my hd. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may try booting from a live cd, you can use elementary or ubuntu or other, and use the disk utility to format or delete the partitions. Then after format or delete the hard disk, try to reboot with another os.

Answer (score 0):

When you would install a new OS, try Debian instead elementaryOS if you are looking for a very stable OS, you should delete all partitions, or let automatic installer work.